# How to get user's manager if user's userAccountControl is 514

Tags: python, ldap

```
import pprint
import ldap

connect = ldap.initialize('ldap://ldap.microhard.com')
connect.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)  #
connect.simple_bind_s('user@microhard.com', 'password')

result = connect.search_s('dc=microhard,dc=com',
                          ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
                          'userAccountControl={}'.format('514'),
                          ['manager'],
                          )
pprint.pprint(result)
```

I found that when i filter the accounts whose `userAccountControl` is 514, their `manager` field in `result` is always nothing.
But i still want to get their manager, so is it possible?

---------------- Updated --------------- 

**Pagination**

```
import pprint
import ldap
from ldap.controls import SimplePagedResultsControl

page_control = SimplePagedResultsControl(True, size=20, cookie='')

connect = ldap.initialize('ldap://ldap.micohard.com')
connect.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)  #
connect.simple_bind_s('user@micohard.com', 'password')

response = connect.search_ext(
    'dc=micohard,dc=com',
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
    'userAccountControl={}'.format('514'),
    serverctrls=[page_control]
)


# ----------- Get 3 pages data -----------
result = []
pages = 0
while True:
    pages += 1
    if pages == 2:
        break
        
    rtype, rdata, rmsgid, serverctrls = connect.result3(response)
    result.extend(rdata)
    controls = [control for control in serverctrls
                if control.controlType == SimplePagedResultsControl.controlType]
    if not controls:
        print('The server ignores RFC 2696 control')
        break
    if not controls[0].cookie:
        break
    page_control.cookie = controls[0].cookie
    response = connect.search_ext(
        'dc=micohard,dc=com',
        ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
        'userAccountControl={}'.format('514'),
        # 'objectClass=group',
        serverctrls=[page_control]
    )

pprint.pprint(result)
```

I picked sevelal users by pagination, and find that some users has `manager` and some not.
And looks like the users who has `manager` left company not too long time ago.
So i guess it might be that the LDAP server syncs data periodically.

Comment: Did you verify (with a different tool) that the data is still there? If the field content is removed in AD for all disabled (514=512+2=NORMAL_ACCOUNT+ACCOUNTDISABLE) users, then no, ofc that's not possible.

Comment: I guess the manager is removed, some removed and some not. I have updated the question's description.